# Proof of the infinitude of primes.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

My goal is to prove there are an infinitude of primes by any *new* bizarre method.

I don't have the maths skills to devise my own proof, so I google'd a lot
and stumbled upon [Ingham's result](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1947-53-06/S0002-9904-1947-08849-2/S0002-9904-1947-08849-2.pdf) that shows

$$p_{n+1} - p_n \lt K p_n^{\frac{5}{8}}$$

where $K$ is a fixed positive integer, is an upper bound for the prime gaps and $p_n$ denotes the $n^{th}$ prime number.

**Lemma**. If $N$ is an integer greater than $K^8$ there exists a prime $p$ such that $$N^3<p<(N+1)^3-1$$

**Proof.** Let $p_n$ be the greatest prime less than $N^3$. Then

$$
\begin{align}
N^3 &< p_{n+1} \\
&< K p_n^{5/8} + p_n \\
&< N^3 + KN^{15/8} \\
&< N^3 + N^2 \ \ \ \text{(since $N>K^8$)} \\
&< N^3 +3N^2 +3N = \left({N + 1}\right)^3 - 1
\end{align}
$$

**Question**

Is it valid to use this result to prove the infinitude of primes?
$$
N^3 < p_{n+1} < \left({N + 1}\right)^3 - 1
$$

For example,

```
   N=1      N=2        N=3        N=4
[1,...,7][8,...,26][27,...,63][64,...,124]...
```

i.e., between any two successive terms of the sequence there is at least one prime, and all these primes are necessarily different. $\blacksquare$

Comment: I'd say it depends on whether Ingham needed to assume the infinitude of primes in order to prove the result you quote. If so, then you would be guilty of circular reasoning, and your "proof" would be invalid.

Comment: Assuming that inequality does not assume infinitely many primes, you are using something which is far more difficult to derive in order to prove something which is simpler to derive.

Comment: The proof is indeed valid, but the result you quoted is implicitly based on the fact that there are infinitely many primes.

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki: I guess that would count as a success in finding a "bizarre method" :-)

Comment: If Ingham's inequality is true of any prime $p_n$, then $p_{n+1}$ exists. No need for further computations.